# Are Estonia, Iceland, Hungary and Greece in a similar economical level?

Tags: international-economics, european-union, political

I was wondering whether the Estonian or the Icelandic economies, despite being small, are relatively close to the Hungarian and the Greek economies, or whether they are much smaller

Therefore, are Estonia, Iceland, Hungary and Greece in a similar economical level? Or on the contrary, the Hungarian and Greek economies are much bigger than the Estonian and the Icelandic ones?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In per capita terms Iceland and Estonia are richer and more developed economies  than Greece or Hungary, but in absolute terms they are smaller (see [OECD data](https://data.oecd.org/gdp/gross-domestic-product-gdp.htm)).

This is because both Greece and Hungary have much larger population.

[image]